# Parameters in SQL aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

Here's an example of a table I'm working with:

```
|  Name | RunTime | TestNum | Replication |
|:-----:|:-------:|:-------:|:-----------:|
| File1 | 12      | 1       | 1           |
| File1 | 34      | 1       | 2           |
| File1 | 76      | 1       | 3           |
| File2 | 91      | 1       | 1           |
| File2 | 52      | 1       | 2           |
| File2 | 73      | 1       | 3           |
| File1 | 61      | 2       | 1           |
| File1 | 31      | 2       | 2           |
| File1 | 53      | 2       | 3           |
| File2 | 43      | 2       | 1           |
| File2 | 49      | 2       | 2           |
| File2 | 11      | 2       | 3           |
```

I'm trying to determine a query where I can select the aggregate `RunTime` for each specific `TestNum` for all 3 `Replications`. I know about the `Avg` function in SQL but I'm still very flimsy on the difference between using a where clause verses group by. So how could i write a query to produce this output?

```
|  Name | Aggregate | TestNum |
|:-----:|:---------:|:-------:|
| File1 | 40.6      | 1       |
| File2 | 72        | 1       |
| File1 | 48.3      | 2       |
| File2 | 34.3      | 2       |
```

Comment: There are not any question marks in your post. What is your question?

Comment: This is not a question, it's a to-do list.

Answer (score 2):

You just need an aggregation function and group by:

```
SELECT Name, AVG(RunTime) Aggregate, TestNum
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name, TestNum
```

In short, when using `group by` vs `where`, the former should be used when aggregating data and the latter should be used when subsetting data.